# Matlab image denoiding using the tikhonov regularization and the RMSProp optimizer

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

My problem is the psnr is change and is converge but the image after denoise is not changing. I am not sure which part is error.  [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf7ST.jpg)

```
function [x,RelErr] =rmsprop(y,mu,lamda,nit,tol, n); 

x = y;
[D DT DTD] = DiffOper(sqrt(n));
epsilon =1e-8;
cache = zeros(size(x));
gradient = x-y+ 2*lamda*DTD*x;
```

Update the gradient using RMSProp
The gradient above is the gradient after differientate from the tikhonov regularization function

```
for k = 1:nit
    x_old = x;
    cache = 0.9* cache + 0.1 * gradient.^2;
    x = x_old - (mu/sqrt(cache+epsilon))*gradient;

    RelErr(k) = norm(x-x_old,'fro')/norm(x,'fro');

    if RelErr(k) < tol
        break;
    end

end
       
end
```

```
function [B Bt BtB] = DiffOper(N)
D = spdiags([-ones(N,1) ones(N,1)], [0 1], N,N+1);
D(:,1) = [];
D(1,1) = 0;
B = [ kron(speye(N),D) ; kron(D,speye(N)) ];
Bt = B';
BtB = Bt*B;
end
```

Main part

```
clc;
clear all;

N = 256; n = N^2;
x = double(imread('foot.png'));
x = imresize(x,[N N]);
sigma = 0.09;  % This is the additive gaussian noise level. Th larger, the noisier the image
y = x(:) + sigma*max(x(:))*randn(n,1);

mu = 0.05;
nit = 1000;
tol = 1e-10;
lamda = 1.0;
[v,Err] = rmsprop(y,mu,lamda,nit,tol, n);
```

Plotting the three figure
1)Original
2)Noisy Image
3)Denoised Image

```
figure;
colormap gray;
subplot(221); imagesc(x); axis image; title(sprintf('Original')) ;

subplot(222); imagesc(reshape(y,N,N)); axis image; title(sprintf('Noisy(PSNR = %3.3f dB,SSIM = %3.3f)',psnr_fun(y,x),ssim_index(reshape(y,N,N),x)));

subplot(223); imagesc(reshape(v,N,N)); axis image; 
title(sprintf('Tikhonov(PSNR = %3.3f dB,SSIM = %3.3f)',psnr_fun(v,x),ssim_index(reshape(v,N,N),x)));

figure;
semilogy(Err,'Linewidth',2.5,'Color','black');
xlabel('Iterations (k)','FontSize',20,'Interpreter', 'latex');
ylabel('Relative Error','FontSize',20,'Interpreter', 'latex');
axis tight;
grid on;
l = legend('RMSProp', 'latex');
set(l,'interpreter','latex','FontSize', 25);
set(gca, 'FontSize',20)
```